TypeError: (0 , import_preact_render_to_string.renderToString) is not a function
I have a very basic setup for an Express.js application and am trying to add Auth.js to it. When I do so the API starts up however when loading any path beyond /api/auth it causes the below stack trace and no logs in the console. Only other indication of an issue is it redirects to /api/auth/error?error=Configuration
[auth][error] TypeError: (0 , import_preact_render_to_string.renderToString) is not a function
api:dev:at send (/Users/josh/projects/saas-starter-kit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/pages/index.js:13:350)
api:dev:at Object.error (/Users/josh/projects/saas-starter-kit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/pages/index.js:119:20)
api:dev:at AuthInternal (/Users/josh/projects/saas-starter-kit/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:31:31)
api:dev:at Auth (/Users/josh/projects/saas-starter-kit/node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:109:34)
api:dev:at <anonymous> (/Users/josh/projects/saas-starter-kit/node_modules/@auth/express/index.js:141:45)

How to reproduce
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                           
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "outDir": "./dist",                            
    "esModuleInterop": true,         
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  }
}

index.ts
import { logger } from '@repo/logger'
import 'dotenv/config'
import { createServer } from './server'

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
const server = createServer()

server.listen(port, async() => {
    logger.info(`api server is starting: Date: ${new Date()}`)
})

server.ts
import express, { type Express } from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'

import { ExpressAuth } from "@auth/express"
import GitHub from "@auth/express/providers/github"

export const createServer = (): Express => {
 const app = express()

 app
  .use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .use(express.json())
  .set("trust proxy", true)
  .use("/api/auth/*", ExpressAuth({
    debug: true,
    trustHost: true,
    providers: [
      GitHub
    ],
   }))
    .get('/status', (_, res) => {
     return res.json({ ok: true })
    })


    return app
}

.env.local
AUTH_SECRET=""
AUTH_GITHUB_ID=""
AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET=""
AUTH_URL="http://localhost:3001/api/auth"

command to start up
dotenvx run --env-file ./.env.local -- nodemon --exec \"node -r esbuild-register ./src/index.ts\" -e .ts

Expected behavior
I would have expected the signin page to load something rather than a server console error message.

In my case the same problem was because of 'CommonJS' module, that Im using on my project. Honestly speaking I don't know how it is related... but my solution was to use dynamic imports, because cofigure typescript was become too difficult for me.
I write AuthJsDepencencies loader to incapslate these details out of my project and use it something like:
async function main() {
  const app = express()
  const authHandler = await AuthJsDependencies.load()
  app.use('/auth/*', authHandler) 
}


If interesting - not the best example of async singletone to load dependencies.
Important!
The most weird thing was is CommonJS + dynamic imoprts.
As mentined here How to prevent typescript from transpiling dynamic imports into require()? IT IS IMPOSIIBLE... but the proposition with eval is worked for me.
import type { ExpressAuth } from "@auth/express";
import type Google from "@auth/express/providers/google";
import type SequelizeAdapter from "@auth/sequelize-adapter";

type Target = {
  ExpressAuth: typeof ExpressAuth;
  SequelizeAdapter: typeof SequelizeAdapter;
  Google: typeof Google;
};

export class AuthJsDependencies {
  private static target?: Target;

  public static async load() {
    if (!AuthJsDependencies.target) {
      AuthJsDependencies.target = await AuthJsDependencies._load();
    }

    return this.target!;
  }

  public static async _load() {
    const [
      { ExpressAuth },
      { default: SequelizeAdapter },
      { default: Google },
    ] = await Promise.all([
      eval('import("@auth/express")'),
      eval('import("@auth/sequelize-adapter")'),
      eval('import("@auth/express/providers/google")'),
    ]);

    return {
      ExpressAuth,
      SequelizeAdapter,
      Google,
    } as Target;
  }
}


